# Trying to add 'buy-buttons' from Ewid e-commerce platform to a site made with wordpress and ACF plugin without success

Tags: html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro, buybutton.js

My ultimate goal is to install ecommerce code into parts of my site. I have a site for displaying the furniture that I sell, but so far it is only showing it. It is impossible to buy it. For that reason I am experimenting with ecommerce tools. They usually offer the possibility to generate a piece of html code that renders a button (Buy). This buy-now-button offers a potential customer the possibility to initiate a purchasing process in the background through this ecommerce tool. You can add this buying button to each of your products.

The ecommerce platform I am using is: ecwid

Here is a copy of my site on an aws ec2 instance: http://18.192.207.65/

Would it be helpful for you to see the wp admin?

Now after I copied that code -- as for instance this one:

```
<div class="ecsp ecsp-SingleProduct-v2 ecsp-Product ec-Product-239733147" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" data-single-product-id="239733147"><div class="ecsp-title" itemprop="name" style="display:none;" content="Argo Libro"></div><div customprop="addtobag"></div></div><script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="https://app.ecwid.com/script.js?37244049&data_platform=singleproduct_v2" charset="utf-8"></script><script type="text/javascript">xProduct()</script>
```

-- but I don't know how to integrate it into the custom fields (for ACF) for each product, so that it shows the button.
Do you have any idea how to solve this riddle (at least for me)?

I have done the same with a Squarespace and it works just fine. But with Wordpresss.... . I am getting desperate because I have tried all kinds resources and friends. But it seems this problem is quite special. The Wordpress maker of my site is unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you'd like to add the Buy Now buttons using the Advanced Custom field plugin in your website built with Wordpress.

I assume you're using the Ecwid Integration code for the Buy Now buttons. If so, I recommend doing the following:

1. Delete Ecwid integration code;
2. Install Ecwid plugin;
3. Add the shortcodes for the Buy Now buttons.

To install the Ecwid plugin, please follow the detailed guide below:

1. Open your WordPress admin panel and go to Plugins.
2. Click the Add New button.
3. Type "ecwid" in the search field. Click Install Now next to the Ecwid E-commerce Shopping Cart plugin.
4. Click Activate.
5. Select the Connect your store option and give the requested permissions to the Ecwid plugin.

The video tutorial on how to add Ecwid plugin on Wordpress is available via the link below: https://youtu.be/Pt1OAkqJSuA

As it's done, please use the shortcodes for the Buy Now button. Open the link to find the code below: https://support.ecwid.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002137520-Shortcodes-for-adding-store-to-Wordpress#product-card-/-buy-now